# Vercel creates new DB connection for every request

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas, vercel, sapper

I'm working on a new website, and although things were working well as we developed locally we've run into an issue when we tried to deploy on Vercel. The app uses the Sapper framework for both the pages and an API, and a database in MongoDB Atlas that we access through Mongoose. The behavior we have locally is that we `npm run dev` and a single DB connection is made which persists until we shut the app down.

[image: Local logs]

When it gets deployed to Vercel though, the code which makes the DB connection and prints that "DB connection successful" message and is only supposed to run once is instead run on every API request

[image: New DB connection per request]

This seems to quickly get out of hand, reaching our database's limit of 500 connections:
[image: DB connections hits limit]

As a result, after the website is used briefly even by a single user some of our API requests start failing with this error (We have the db accepting any connection rather than an IP whitelist, so the suggestion the error gives isn't helpful):
[image: API can't connect to DB]

Our implementation is that we have a call to `mongoose.connect` in a .js file:

```
mongoose.connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(() => console.log("DB connection successful!")).catch(console.error);
```

and then we `import` that file in Sapper's `server.js`. The recommendation we've been able to find is "just cache the connection", but that hasn't been successful and seems to be more of a `node-mongodb-native` thing. Regardless, this is what we tried which didn't work better or worse locally, but also didn't fix the problems on Vercel:

```
let cachedDb = {};

exports.connection = async () => {
    if (cachedDb.isConnected)
        return;
        try {
            const db = await mongoose.connect(DB, {
                            useNewUrlParser: true,
                            useCreateIndex: true,
                            useFindAndModify: false,
                            useUnifiedTopology: true
                        });
            cachedDb.isConnected = db.connections[0].readyState;
            console.log("DB connection successful!");
            return cachedDb;
        } catch(error) {console.log("Couldn't connect to DB", error);}
```

So... is there a way to make this work without replacing at least one of the pieces? The website isn't live yet so replacing something isn't the end of the world, but "just change a setting" is definitely preferred to starting from scratch.

Comment: You are asking about too many moving pieces. If your framework doesn't manage db connections for you, it has nothing to do with connections being made for every request.

Comment: Otherwise link to documentation in your framework that talks about db connections.

Comment: I thought this was fine - thanks for posting it.

Comment: I enjoyed getting the context to the problem and as bonus I learned about Sapper.

Comment: @Kamil Drakari Would you like to share the solution? I've been burning for this issue for last one month

Comment: @AgentK I think we ended up switching away from Vercel and not using a serverless architecture at all. I don't remember what we switched to though, I'm no longer working on the project.

Comment: @KamilDrakari thanks for the response, I moved from vercel to digitalocean and things are sorted.

Answer (score 8):

#### Summary

Serverless functions on Vercel work like a self-contained process. While it is possible to cache the connection "per function," it is not a good idea to deploy a serverful-ready library to a serverless environment. Here are a few questions that you need to answer:

- Is your framework or DB library caching the connection?
- Is your code prepared for Serverless?
- What type of workload is Vercel optimized for?

#### Further Context

Vercel is an excellent platform for your frontend that would use Serverless Functions as helpers. The CDN available in conjunction with the workflow makes the deployment process very quick and allows you to move faster. Deploying a full-blown API or serverful workload will never be a good idea. Let's suppose I need to use MySQL with Vercel. Instead of [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql), you should use [mysql-serverless](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-mysql), which is optimized for the serverless primitives. Even with that in mind, it will be probably cheaper to just use a VM/Container for the API depending on the level of requests you are expecting. Therefore, we would end up with the following ideal solution:

```
Frontend (Vercel - Serverless) --> Backend (Serverful - External provider) --> DB
```

*Disclaimer: At the moment, I work for Vercel.*

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "while it is possible to cache the connection per function"? If Next API routes are deployed as serverless functions, then by definition, doesn't it mean that these functions cannot share the same state that is `cachedDb`?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the cloud database of MongoDB Atlas, then you can use the [mongodb-data-api](https://github.com/surmon-china/mongodb-data-api) library, which is encapsulated based on the [Data API](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/api/data-api/) of MongoDB Atlas. All data operations are performed through the HTTPS interface, and there is no connection problem.

```js
import { MongoDBDataAPI, Region } from 'mongodb-data-api'

const api = new MongoDBDataAPI({
  apiKey: '<your_mongodb_api_key>',
  appId: '<your_mongodb_app_id>'
})

api
  .findOne({
    dataSource: '<target_cluster_name>',
    database: '<target_database_name>',
    collection: '<target_collection_name>',
    filter: { name: 'Surmon' }
  })
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.document)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

The example codes provided by NextJS say to cache the database connection yet this is the issue that happens with myself as well.

Both here
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/utils/dbConnect.js

And here
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/util/mongodb.js

are caching the connection and if I copy the example i get the same issue as the OP.

It also says here
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

that i can interact directly with my database. Massively conflicting information where I'm told on one hand to cache the connection, while a member of the team tells me its not suitable for this approach despite the docs & examples telling me otherwise. Is this a bug report type situtation?

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the similar issue but I came across an example here:
`https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb/util/mongodb.js`

Apparently the trick is to use the `global` variable:

```js
let cached = global.mongo

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongo = { conn: null, promise: null }
}
```

Comment: i tried this approach with no success, was complaining that it couldnt find mongo of undefined (does global not exist?? *gasp* ) 

which led me to the conclusion that vercel doesn't have a global object in its container....

i ended up stripping back down to the basic example that vercel gives here: 
https://vercel.com/guides/deploying-a-mongodb-powered-api-with-node-and-vercel

Comment: It works for me. The one you're referring to used to crash on me, every now and then. What a strange thing. Weird is that they provide two different approaches, one of them burried in the git repo.

Comment: @JakubPelák did that fix it for you in your development environment or on Vercel?

Comment: @rnbrady I guess both. But I didn't have that issue on localhost.

Comment: I don't think it works well.....  Is it designed only for next.js?

Comment: I don't use it with next.js.