# How to connect to mongodb database using Nextjs?

Tags: mongodb, next.js

Trying to connect to my mongodb database in the latest version of Nextjs. Things have changed so much, so I don't longer know what to do.

There's an example of how to set up the connection here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-mongodb

They use this file:

```
//The mongodb.js file from the example
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {}

let client
let clientPromise

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Please add your Mongo URI to .env.local')
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  if (!global._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
    global._mongoClientPromise = client.connect()
  }
  clientPromise = global._mongoClientPromise
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
  clientPromise = client.connect()
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise
```

However, they forgot to add how to actually use it. I can't even begin to figure it out.

```
//pages/api/user.js

import client from '/lib/mongodb.js'

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  //How do I connect here?
}
```

And two bonus questions:

- I used to do caching on my database connection. Is it not needed anymore?
- What happened to the `utils` folder? It used to be special, in that it didn't send anything there to the client. Now everyone seem to use `lib` but I don't think there's anything special with it?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210690/mongodb-atlas-connections-to-clusters-exceeded-nextjs-nextauth/) have some examples, and since you are using Vercel too, there are bonus answers to the problems you didn't discover yet.

Comment: @AlexBlex Thanks. Can't find a single clear answer to any of my questions though.

Comment: @AlexBlex I'm reading through your comments and trying my best to understand. My head is spinning very fast from all this! I understand it's pointless to cache in a serverless environment. I still would very very much like to avoid creating a wholly separate backend for my API! What is a serverless Atlas subscription, or data-api?

Comment: @AlexBlex OTOH I don't really understand why caching can't work. Sure, the function closes, but why can't the connection to the database remain..? It works on my live production on an older Nextjs version, which still uses serverless functions.

Comment: Atlas is a managed mongodb hosting. DB-as-a-service. You can try free tier https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/database   As any service it comes with limits. One of them is number of connections. On dedicated host you are limited by OS - 65k sockets. Connection cannot be cached because of Vercel architecture. The mongo driver opens a persistent connection that can be reused, but only within the same nodejs process. Once the process dies, the connection is lost. Examples how to use the connection is in the question itself. Well, with few mistakes, but you should get the idea.

Comment: @AlexBlex Guess I have to have a separate REST server.

Comment: It depends (c) =) The OP there had an issue because free atlas tier allows only 500 connections. If you use self-hosted server your limit is like x100 bigger, so not necessarily a problem.

Comment: @AlexBlex Isn't it a problem opening up thousands of connections?

Comment: Only if it is cause problems =)  World is not ideal and at some point you need to compromise quality for the sake of feasibility. It's up to you how to balance it. Considering you have picked managed low-maintenance app hosting, I assume number of open connections is not a concern unless it affects functionality visible from business level, right?

Comment: @AlexBlex I suppose so! I'm honestly a little disappointed with Nextjs/Vercel on this. The benefits of a serverless environment are intangible to me, but the drawbacks are very real. I tried the Data API on Atlas but it was 12-15 times slower than the driver by the way. Maybe it's faster on a real Cluster instead of the free one?

Comment: Right tools in the right hands do miracles in the intended usecases. Vercel positions itself as a platform to host clientside apps: "enables frontend teams to do their best work." Essentially hosting of static content with **support** of dynamic content, API, databases, and many other things. Whilst it is focused to make Nextjs shine where it's best, the auxiliary technologies are not the most efficient. They may improve in the future, may even take over the frontend component. After all AWS started as a bookstore.

Comment: @Yeats GH knows the difference between "Mine" and "mine". Your OS may not, e.g., some OSes are case-preserving-but-insensitive.

Comment: is it secure this aproach ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
const dbClient = await client;
const db = dbClient.db('db-name');
const collection = db.collection('collection-name');
// example to get a doc in collection
const doc = await collection.findOne({query:""}, {...options})
```