# How to Restart Application Server on Vercel When Only "Redeploy" Option is Available?

Tags: mongodb, next.js, vercel

I'm currently hosting a Next.js application on Vercel, and I've encountered an issue where I need to restart the application server. However, in my Vercel dashboard, I can only find a "Redeploy" option, and there is no explicit "Restart" option.

I received an alert from my MongoDB hosting service recommending that I restart my application server to address a connection limit issue. The email suggested restarting the application server as a short-term solution.

Is it possible to effectively restart the application server using the "Redeploy" feature on Vercel? If so, how can I achieve this? I want to ensure that I'm following best practices to manage my Next.js application hosted on Vercel.

Answer (score 1):

Vercel is serverless, there is nothing to restart.

The email suggests to restart the server because it's a canned alert, and there is no visibility of your application architecture from mongodb side anyway, so don't take is literally.

Finally, there is not much that you can do. Poor connection management is a known limitation of Vercel + Mondgodb native architecture.

See details in [Mongoose creating too many connections in NextJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76645619/mongoose-creating-too-many-connections-in-nextjs) You might be able to soften the impact by tweaking configuration, but ultimately the only option is to use HTTP API instead of native driver.

Atlas provides Data API by default, or you can go with custom API using Atlas functions. Alternatively you can introduce a server to your architecture to handle database related tasks.

Comment: How I can install easily my own MongoDB? I thought to install it in AWS, but seems it is not possible. Maybe I should migrate to DynamoDB or DocumentDB? https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-install-mongodb-in-aws-ec2

Comment: "in AWS, but seems it is not possible." - it is exactly what Atlas is - the managed cluster on AWS or Azure. It is definitely possible, and the page you referred kinda describes how to do it. It won't solve the problem tho. You will just buy bigger connection pool at expense of looking after the cluster yourself. Mongo is quite easy to install, but it requires efforts to maintain. DocumentDB is driver-compatible with Mongo, so it will suffer from the same issue with open connections. DynamoDB - no comments. I don't believe you meant to put it here.