# How to optimze FCP, LCP in Nextjs 14 or 13 (source code, published url)

Tags: next.js, vanilla-extract

I use Nextjs 14, Vanilla Extract, mongoDB, Vercel

It takes 2.5 sec at least and 5 sec maximum to move another pages. (with no cache)

And it takes 2 sec at least to change theme. (When I click the toggle button)

The reason I supposed is the way I use vanilla extract or layout(located in post folder)

Vanila Extract theme code is

```
/** rootlayout */

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  const theme = cookieStore.get("theme");
  return (
    <html lang="ko-KR">
      <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
      <body className={theme?.value === "light" ? ligthTheme : darkTheme}>
        <Topbar />
        <div className={styles.mainContentContainer}>
          <main className={styles.mainContent}>
            {children}
            <Footer />
          </main>
        </div>
        <BottomBar />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

```
/** toggle button */
import { moon } from "../icon/moon";
import { sun } from "../icon/sun";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import { toggleBtn } from "./ToggleBtn.css";
import SVGmorph from "./SVGmorph";

export default function ToggleBtn() {
  const theme = cookies().get("theme");
  const handleTheme = async () => {
    "use server";
    if (theme?.value === "dark" || !theme?.value) {
      cookies().set("theme", "light");
    } else {
      cookies().set("theme", "dark");
    }
  };
  return (
    <form action={handleTheme}>
      <button className={toggleBtn}>
        <svg
          width="28"
          height="28"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          fill="none"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        >
          <SVGmorph paths={[sun, moon, sun]} theme={theme?.value || "dark"} />
        </svg>
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

and css in component
`background: vars.themeColor.backgroundColor.glassGradientColorTop`

I've tried everything for three days, but I can't find solution.

What is wrong with my code? I appreciate a little advice, so please help me...

source code : https://github.com/22JH/blog
published url : https://www.joo-dev.com/

[score in vercel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0IUa.png)

And when I deleted the post layout it becomes much better.(But it still takes a long time to change theme)

I tried delete svg morph and it still takes a long time.

I changed the fetch code (add api folder and route.ts). But it still takes a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest impact to your performance is everytime you fetch data you establish new connection to database using `connectToDB()` function and you install to many dependecy.

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed my mongoose.ts like this
```
if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
    try {
      await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
      console.log("MongoDB connected");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("MongoDB connection already established");
    return;
  }
```
But it still takes a long time to change the theme. 
And can you give me the advice to optimze mongoDB? I think it is little slow to load data

Comment: this is also issue on the vercel since you also deploy on vercel, here i found solution to this topic [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76645619/mongoose-creating-too-many-connections-in-nextjs)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I solved all problems.